# How to stop Nginx worked as explicit proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a website on Nginx. When I put an IP of this website as explicit proxy on my browser and request any website the NGINX, it redirect me to my website.

How can I stop NGINX worked as proxy at all? Where should be to configure that on NGINX.conf or site-available?